# Faceted Search and Aggregations Do Not Work Properly

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have an index for a Store with a type for Items, i.e. `/store/items`.
among other properties, Items have a `Title` (**analyzed** text), a 
`Description` (**analyzed** text), and `Tags` (**not_analyzed** text).

I want to be able to show the facets over Tags with counts, so if a 
facet of the Tag "Yellow" has a count of 12, for example, then when the 
user adds that Tag to the filter she will see only 12 items.

I am using a Filtered Query with Aggs, as shown below, on Elasticsearch 
1.1.1 on a single node:

```
GET _search {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Large Widgets",
          "fields": [
            "title^3",
            "description"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "tags": [
            "Colorful"
          ],
          "execution": "and"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "available_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags"
      }
    },
    "size": 20
  }
}
```

I have two problems:

1. No matter what value I pass for the aggs/size I get 10 aggregations.
   I want to get more than 10.
2. The hits count that comes back when adding the new tag to the filter 
   doesn't match the doc_count that came with the aggregations, for 
   example, the aggregations might show a doc_count of 12 for the tag 
   "Yellow", but if I add "Yellow" to the filter terms so that it reads 
   `"tags": [ "Colorful", "Yellow" ]`I get 17 hits instead of the expected 12.

This usually does not happen at the first level, but only in subsequent drill down.

am I doing something wrong?  is there a bug somewhere?

this is a cross [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/xYRaJa04wfc/VyeV-XzgDVcJ) from the Elasticsearch mailing list which didn't get enough attention

Answer (score 1):

1. Shard_size cannot be smaller than the size, so you may have a larger size than shard_size. In which case Elasticsearch will override it to be equal to shard_size.
2. Does the filtered results for "Colorful" "and" "Yellow" equal 17 documents instead of the 12 "Yellow" documents?

Comment: 1) I have the default of 5 Shards on that index.  you may be onto something with the shard_size though.  2) I get more documents than what the agg showed, so in that example yes, the agg shows 12 documents but when I drill down 17 documents show up.  I noticed that this happens when the agg shows a low value, so possibly aggs that show less than (shard_size * aggs_size), i.e. (5 * 10), I see that issue consistently.

Comment: Let me know if you find the answer and I'll change my answer, or you can add an Edit, whichever works.